# PayPal Payment - Not sure what todo

Tags: paypal

Not sure if this forum is even for PalPal..

Anyways, Lets say I have $100 in my PayPal, and $10 in my bank account. If I make a purchase of $110 on PalPal through Ebay, would PayPal take $100 out of my balance and then $10 from my bank..or would they immediately try to take $110 out of my bank account?

Comment: "Developer resources to use PayPal APIs are available at https://developer.paypal.com . Ask questions if you are a software developer only. If you are a PayPal user, contact Paypal using their site."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal will deduct the amount you have in your PayPal account from the total and you will only need to bill the remainder to your account.